# Science fiction movie featuring a gynoid that becomes conscious and escapes her place of work

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can only recall fragments of this film and would love to figure out what it was so I can rewatch it.

The main character had an Asian background, as I recall. At the start of the film we see her waking up or coming to at nights when she is not supposed to and wandering around trying to figure things out. She is surrounded by a lot of other females who look very much or exactly like her, so she's a robot or a clone.

The women work as waitresses in a casino or gaming hall. I think there is a scene where she is aware while serving tables and has to pretend not to be.

Blank. Then action scene where she escapes with the help of someone. I see them running along narrow unenclosed skyways that connect skyscrapers.

My sense is that all of this is at or towards the beginning and there is a lot more plot that comes after.

Comment: This sounds a bit like the Neo Seoul 2144 segment of [Cloud Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Atlas_(film)) except that I don't remember Sonmi-451 as not being supposed to be aware, except in the socio-political sense.

Comment: @DavidW Yes! That's it! It helps me understand why my memories of it are fragmented :D

Comment: @lofidevops The movie itself is fragmented. It involves multiple stories in the long past, past, present, future and far future.

Comment: +1 for TIL that 'gynoid' is a word to describe female droids.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As identified in the comments by @DavidW, the movie is Cloud Atlas, in particular the story ["An Orison of Sonmi-451"](https://cloudatlas.fandom.com/wiki/An_Orison_of_Sonmi-451). Sonmi-451 is a fabricant (human clone) working at a fast food restaurant. From the synopsis:

> Sonmi continues her story and tells of her friend, Yoona-939, a fellow sister server, who began to be aware of her surroundings, develop curiosity, and to question her lot in the world. This awareness in fabricants is referred to in the novel as "ascending."

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the HBO series Westworld, which features some Asian gynoids amidst skyscrapers in later seasons.

Comment: Similar themes, but I have only watched the first season! :)